# php string to flash variables

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I am using AS3 for a project and I have to send some flash variables to PHP, check the MySQL databese and the to return some results to Flash. I do this with this:
`new URLRequest(URL + "?p=" + SelectedCountry + "&action=check&nocache=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000)));`

and the php code just checks the MySQL if there is a row with the selected country:

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == "check") {

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE country = '".$_REQUEST['p']."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($q) == 0) {
        echo "nqma";
    } else {
        echo "ima";
    }
}
```

OK, that's fine and it works, because I can use this in Flash:

```
if(e.target.data == "ima") {
    uiRepCountryLabel.text = "Ima";
} 
if(e.target.data == "nqma") {
    uiRepCountryLabel.text = "Nqma";
}
```

But what if I want to make the php result to look like this:

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == "check") {
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE country = '".$_REQUEST['p']."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($q) == 0) {
        echo "res=nqma";
    } else {
        echo "res=ima&hisCountry=Bulgaria&hisPhoneNumber=000000123&hisCity=Svishtov&his.....";
    }
}
```

How can I use this format In Flash? I know, that many of you will tell me to use AMFPHP, but I am not able, because my client doesn't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var appheader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream"); 
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URL + "?p=" + SelectedCountry + "&action=check&nocache=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000)));

urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(appheader);
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var urlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlRequest);
urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onUploadComplete);
urlloader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
urlloader.load(urlRequest);

urlloader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleGetSessionIOError);
}



function handleGetSessionIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {   
 trace("handleGetSessionIOError "+e);

}



function onUploadComplete(e:Event):void {   
trace("uploaded to server."+e.target.data);

}
```

Comment: OK, but how to use the multivars php result?

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to crooksy's post:

```
function onUploadComplete(e:Event)
{   
    var phpvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);

    trace(phpvars.res,phpvars.hisCountry);
}
```